# Copy Software from on IOS-Device to another

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, access-point, aironet

I have 3 Aironet Access Points.

2 are running on Version 15.3(3)JBB1 and when I factory resetted and its actually running on Version 15.2(4)JB3a.

I wanted to copy the Configuration of on of the AP to the resetted one. But they are not on the same software and I think, this is the reason why i don't work right.

We don't have an active contract (I asked) with Cisco. Is it possible to get the Image from one AP to another? And which file is it?

Here's the output of the flash:

```
AP#show flash: 

Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx           4   Sep 4 2015 14:32:44 +00:00  FOC17304FJT
    3  -rwx         405   Mar 1 1993 00:00:19 +00:00  env_vars
   44  drwx         768  Jul 31 2013 06:41:27 +00:00  c1140-k9w7-mx.153-3.JBB1
    5  -rwx        9010  Jul 31 2013 06:41:33 +00:00  event.log
    4  -rwx        2572  Dec 10 2015 14:18:02 +00:00  private-config
    7  drwx         128  Jul 31 2013 06:37:10 +00:00  c1140-rcvk9w8-mx
   43  drwx           0  Jul 31 2013 06:38:16 +00:00  configs
    6  -rwx        5182  Dec 10 2015 14:18:02 +00:00  config.txt
   10  -rwx        7192  Dec 10 2015 14:18:02 +00:00  private-multiple-fs
```

`c1140-k9w7-mx.153-3.JBB1` is a fodler where I think the image is stored. But I need a tar file (for upgrading with gui).

What should I do? Are isn't it possible to upgrade the one AP and i have to stay at 15.2 with this one.

UPDATE1:

```
AP#copy flash:/c1140-k9w7-mx.153-3.JBB1/c1140-k9w7-xx.153-3.JBB1 ftp://ftpuser:ftppassword@IP//home/upload/
Address or name of remote host [IP]? 
Destination filename [/home/upload/c1140-k9w7-xx.153-3.JBB1]? 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
7954956 bytes copied in 7.184 secs (1107316 bytes/sec)
```

But it isn't there:

```
ls -la /home/upload/
insgesamt 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 ftpuser ftpuser 4096 Apr  5 15:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root    4096 Apr  5 11:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftpuser ftpuser  220 Apr  5 11:59 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftpuser ftpuser 3515 Apr  5 11:59 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    5015 Apr  5 13:46 config.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftpuser ftpuser  675 Apr  5 11:59 .profile
```

UPDATE2: show Flash on resetted AP

```
AP2#show flash: 

Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx        1892   Mar 1 1993 00:16:52 +00:00  event.log
    3  -rwx        1909   Apr 5 2016 12:51:55 +00:00  private-config
    4  -rwx        3096   Apr 5 2016 12:51:55 +00:00  private-multiple-fs
    5  drwx        2048   Jan 1 1970 00:00:03 +00:00  ap1g1-k9w7-mx.152-4.JB3a
  198  -rwx         286   Mar 1 1993 01:14:07 +00:00  env_vars
  199  -rwx        5425   Apr 5 2016 12:51:55 +00:00  config.txt

131334144 bytes total (118214656 bytes free)
```

Comment: Run  a show version command on the Aironet AP to determine which of those directories hides your IOS bin.

Comment: That wouldn't exactly be legal. You need to have a contract with Cisco for that device to upgrade software.

Comment: But I already had the Software. Before i had done the factory reset. @RonMaupin Is there a time when you are not online? ;-)

Comment: If you already had that software, it is still on the device. You probably just need to set the boot parameters.

Comment: Ron is correct, I must have glanced over that fact.

Comment: Really? Even if I made the Factory Reset? Holding the Mode button untin the Flash LED turns Amber? This would also help me if it is still there. Somewhere on the Flash.

Comment: Did you check the flash on the device as Ron suggested?

Comment: Yep. just made on Update on the Questions. Seems that it isn't there.

Comment: Have you checked all the directories? if it isn't there and you don't have licensing than you can't legally move the IOS.

Comment: Yep, there is only one. Nothing useful in there. Damnit.

Comment: You two seem very pro, you know if a configuration made in 15.3 will work on 15.2?

Comment: Are the access points all the same model? Directory listings make me think they are different models (an 1140 and a 700 series). You can't copy the image from one model to a different model and expect it to work.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As per Ron's comment, if you can't get the licensed IOS from Cisco than you don't have the correct licensing required to upgrade.

Comment: I also respond to you comment: i've done a run version before, therefore i know the "System image file is "flash:/c1140-k9w7-mx.153-3.JBB1/c1140-k9w7-xx.153-3.JBB1" ".
I've tried it with this command to copy it to my Server. Please see Question UPDATE1.

Comment: Please see Ron's comment. If you can't get the IOS from cisco than you are performing the upgrade against their licensing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

On AP make tftp server:

```
conf t
 tftp-server flash:c1140-k9w7-mx.153-3.JBB1/c1140-k9w7-xx.153-3.JBB1
```

On AP2 download IOS from AP tftp

```
copy tftp: flash:
!And fill all required parameters
```

It need AP's have connection between each other